# Removing a usercontrol by clicking a button on it

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, winrt-xaml

I have a GridView which shows certain items in it. Each item has a edit button into it, pressing the edit button loads a usercontrol next to the item. This usercontrol has a close button into it, pressing the close button removes the usercontrol. [image: GridView with the items(blue color rectangles)]

[image: GridView after the edit button on the item(blue color rectangles) is clicked and usercontrol(red color rectangle) is loaded next to it]

Blue color rectangles represent the items in the gridview. On clicking the pink add button the red color usercontrol loads up. Now on the clicking the close button on the red rectangle it should remove the red color item and revert to the original state. 
I have added the usercontrol using template selector and it is working fine. But the close button does not remove it. I have tried the following approach for removing :

`(GridView)this.Parent).Items.Remove(this);`

On adding a breakpoint and then checking I found that  this.Parent is null. I am stuck.How do I proceed? I am using c#, xaml, winrt, visual studio 2012

Comment: I heard the parent-property is not set automatically in the constructor. Have you tried to set the parent manually after making the control? Like `yourobj.parent=topobject`?

Comment: Hi @Julian Thanx :) Actually that is not possible as the usercontrol is basically a data template. I changed the datacontext which solved my problem for the time being :)

Comment: It is considered polite to mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to work up the visual tree, try this:

```
var _Parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(sender as UserControl) as GridView;
_Parent.Items.Remove(sender as UserControl);
```

But removing items from a GridView should be done by manipulating an ObservableCollection bound to the ItemsSource of the GridView in the ViewModel. Not like this, probably...